# Navigation bar that tells where you are

Tags: jquery, css, web, navigation, jquery-waypoints

I'm not sure how to ask this, so there it goes:

I have a webpage where you click on a nav bar and it scrolls down or up to where the part is, but you can also manualy scroll to wherever you want.

My problem is that I need the currenly viewed section to be highlighted on the navigation bar (say, slightly brigter color), which is easy to do on click but can't seem to make it work with the scroll (both up and down). I tried using the JQuery library [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about), but I it seems to be a little complicated for me (JQuery Syntax is kind of confusing) and never got it to activate on both scroll up and down.
Is there an easy solution for this? What would you recomend? I'd be happier without JQuery, to keep it simple.

I hope I made myself clear, English is not my main languaje and this is one of my first posts on SO.

```
$( "#section1" ).waypoint(function(direction){
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');   
    $(".b1").addClass('highlight');
},{offset:'2px'});

$( "#section2" ).waypoint(function(direction){
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    if (direction == 'Up'){
        $(".b1").addClass('highlight');
    }else{
        $(".b2").addClass('highlight');
    }
},{offset:'2px'});
```

After that there's another bunch of sections identical to #section2 with other numbers, but this code makes the changes only on the top part of the section.
 This is the Section:

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>
            My Spectre around me night and day
            Like a wild beast guards my way;
            My Emanation far within
            Weeps incessantly for my sin.
        </p>

    </div>
```

And this is the navigation

```
<div class="nav"><ul>
    <li><a href="#section1" class="b1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2" class="b2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3" class="b3"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4" class="b4"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5" class="b5"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6" class="b6"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section7" class="b7"></a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've made my own solution for you, I hope you understand!

See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/A6nDa/

It is important to keep class and ids for sections and ul items the same / inline with mine

**HTML + Nav**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1" id="nav-section-1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2" id="nav-section-2">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="section" id="section-1">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>
            My Spectre around me night and day
            Like a wild beast guards my way;
            My Emanation far within
            Weeps incessantly for my sin.
        </p>
</div>

<div class="section" id="section-2">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>
            My Spectre around me night and day
            Like a wild beast guards my way;
            My Emanation far within
            Weeps incessantly for my sin.
        </p>
 </div>
```

**Dummy Styling**

```
.nav ul {
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav ul a {
    color: white;
}
.nav ul a.highlight {
    color: orange;
}
#section-1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    padding:10px;
    background:green;
}
#section-2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    padding:10px;
    background:purple;
    margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
function onScreen() {
    // Check if the top of the page collides with each section
    $('.section').each(function() {
        var windowScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        var navHeight = $('.nav ul').height();

        // Complex line checks if windowScroll (top of page) + nav bar hits Section Top / Bottom
        if( windowScroll + navHeight >= $(this).offset().top && windowScroll + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
            // This section is active! Add Highlight
            $('.nav ul a#nav-' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('highlight');
        } else {
            // No - Remove highlight class
            $('.nav ul a#nav-' + $(this).attr('id')).removeClass('highlight');
        }

    });
}

$(window).on('scroll resize', function () {
    onScreen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult, but perhaps this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zXZPF/1/) will get you started - it's very brute-force and inelegant.

I've adjusted the JS empirically so that when the subtitle comes to the middle of the window, the list item turns red. You might be able to use you present code (the location of #section).

JS

```
var windowscrolllocation;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var windowscrolllocation = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.putmehere').html(windowscrolllocation);
  if (windowscrolllocation > 0 && windowscrolllocation < 120)
     {
      $('.b1').css('background-color', 'red');
      } else {
      $('.b1').css('background-color', 'white');
              }
  if (windowscrolllocation > 120 && windowscrolllocation < 260)
     {
      $('.b2').css('background-color', 'red');
      } else {
      $('.b2').css('background-color', 'white');
              }
  if (windowscrolllocation > 260 && windowscrolllocation < 300)
     {
      $('.b3').css('background-color', 'red');
      } else {
      $('.b3').css('background-color', 'white');
              }
  if (windowscrolllocation > 300 && windowscrolllocation < 350)
     {
      $('.b4').css('background-color', 'red');
      } else {
      $('.b4').css('background-color', 'white');
              }

});
```

Comment: I already posted code that works out position automatically. This is of course a good alternative if you want it to be less flexible. But I would recommend using $('.b1').addClass and removeClass rather than changing the CSS with JQuery